# crt1.o not found when cross compiling on fedora 31

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, meson-build

I'm compiling mesa3d for my raspberry pi4. but I meet some error when running meson build.

```
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: f41392cec8f12086b93952027a77c114
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' '/mesa/build/meson-private/sanitycheckc_cross.exe' '-L/usr/lib' '-pipe' '-D' '_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-v' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64' /usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccvgsZVl.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/sys-root --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -X -EL -maarch64linux -o /mesa/build/meson-private/sanitycheckc_cross.exe crt1.o crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9 /tmp/ccybbKgk.o -lgcc -lc -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/aarch6
4-linux-gnu/9/crtend.o crtn.o
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed glibc-devel.i686 which include crt1.o crti.o and crtn.o. And I can find them in /usr/lib.

I try to set LIBRARY_PATH and use -L /usr/lib , but it seems not work.

My cross config is :

```
[binaries]
c = '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc'
cpp = '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++'
ar = '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar'
strip = '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-strip'
pkgconfig = '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config'
exe_wrapper = '/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static'
[properties]
c_args=['-L/usr/lib']
c++_args=['-L/usr/lib']
c_link_args = ['-L/usr/lib','--verbose' ]
c++_link_args = ['-L/usr/lib','--verbose']

[host_machine]
system = 'linux'
cpu_family = 'aarch64'
cpu = 'aarch64'
endian = 'little'
```

How can I resove this problem? Somebody help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi4 is ARM Cortex-A72 based, so you need appropriate cross tools and specify correct **cpu**, so this is minimum:

```
[binaries]
c = '/usr/lib/ccache/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'
cpp = '/usr/lib/ccache/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++'
ar = '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar'
strip = '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip'
pkgconfig = '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config'

[host_machine]
system = 'linux'
cpu_family = 'arm'
cpu = 'armv7hl'
endian = 'little'
```

Check [this](https://github.com/anholt/mesa/wiki/Raspberry-Pi-cross-compile) for details